# pimpl idiom and template class friend

Tags: c++, templates, friend, pimpl-idiom

I'm trying to use the pimpl idiom to hide some grungy template code, but I can't give derived classes of the body class friend access to the handle class.  I get an error C2248 from MSVC 9 sp1.  Here's some code to duplicate the error:

```
//
// interface.hpp
//
namespace internal{
    template<class T>
    class specific_body;
}

class interface
{
    struct body;
    body *pbody_;
    interface(body *pbody);

    template<class T>
    friend class internal::specific_body;

public:

    ~interface();

    interface(const interface &rhs);

    bool test() const;

    static interface create( bool value );
};

//
// interface.cpp
//
struct interface::body
{
    virtual ~body(){}

    virtual bool test() const = 0;

    virtual interface::body *clone() const = 0;
};

class true_struct {};
class false_struct {};

namespace internal {

template< class T>
class specific_body : public interface::body
{ // C2248
public:

    specific_body(){}

    virtual bool test() const;

    virtual interface::body *clone() const
    {
        return new specific_body();
    }
};

bool specific_body<true_struct>::test() const
{
    return true;
}

bool specific_body<false_struct>::test() const
{
    return false;
}

} //namespace internal

interface::interface(body *pbody) : pbody_(pbody) {}

interface::interface(const interface &rhs) : pbody_(rhs.pbody_->clone()) {}

interface::~interface() { delete pbody_; }

bool interface::test() const
{
    return pbody_->test();
}

interface interface::create(bool value )
{
    if ( value )
    {
        return interface(new internal::specific_body<true_struct>());
    }
    else
    {
        return interface(new internal::specific_body<false_struct>());
    }
}

//
// main.cpp
//
// #include "interface.hpp"
//

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    interface object( interface::create(true));

    if ( object.test() )
    {
        // blah
    }
    else
    {
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, I'm trying to hide `interface::body` and `specific_body` implementations from the users of `interface` if that's not obvious from my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to "solve" this problem by making the `body` a public declaration in the interface.  That solves the C2248 error during the declaration of the `specific_body`.  I also made the `body` a friend to the `interface` class and added a method to the `body` struct:

```
static interface create( body *pbody )
{
    return interface(pbody);
}
```

so that a `specific_body` can create an `interface` if there is a nested relationship between instances of `specific_body`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add template<> in the explicit instantiation of the template test method

```
template<> // add this line
bool specific_body<true_struct>::test() const
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to add those lines to the specialization's of the test method in my example, but they don't help.  Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Check if you are not missing something in your example. Fixing that line it compiles with gcc 4.4.1 and works ok.

Comment: Well, they don't seem to make a difference with Microsoft's compiler, so it looks like a compiler conformance issue then.  Thanks for for your input.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't qualified `specific_body`. Try

```
template<class T>
friend class internal::specific_body;
```

as your friend declaration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it doesn't help though

Comment: Out of interest, does it all start working if you remove namespace `internal` i.e. just put `specific_body` in the global namespace?

Answer (score 0):

Try using typename maybe?  I think I read in Sutter that typename will work to get to class inside of an unknown scope, while class won't.

Comment: I think you put it after or before friend

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the unqualified specific_body mentioned by Troubadour, your specialization attempt of specific_body<>::test for true_struct and false_struct seems incorrect. You have to specialice the full class.

To solve the problem, I'd simply declare *body* in the public section. Declaring specific_body to be a friend of interface::body in addition doesn't help either.

Comment: I'm not sure why fulling specializing the `specific_body` class would matter in this case.

I one case in my code declaring the body public helped, but I have another case where the `specfic_body` needs access to the private constructor of `interface` too; So I would like to solve the friend access issue, or restructure the code to achieve the same end where I can inherent from the body class.

Comment: There is no way around full specialization to make it C++ standards compliant. If you don't get any errors on that part your compiler might support it as an extension, I don't know. But GCC rejects it. Just saying...

Comment: What exactly do you see as non-compliant here? Specializing just a member functon of a template class without specializing the entire class is perfectly legal in C++. Speaking informally, each member function of class template is by itself an independent template, which can be specialized independently. This is a rarely used feature, but it is there. 14.7.3/16 contains an example of such specialization.

Comment: He tries to specialize it without the template keyword

Comment: Oh, yeah, I missed it. I does indeed need the typical explicit specialization syntax with `template<>` bit. But still there's no need to "specialize the full class".